# debugger cannot access the parent page variable in the included page

Tags: java, jsp, intellij-idea, jstl, el

I have parent page named userCreated and I include another page in it named confirmationUser 
using

```
 <%@include file="confirmationUser.jsp" %>
```

in the parent page (userCreated) I have the variable registerUser 
and I am trying to see its value in intellij but I am getting the error when I am using evaluate expression 
Local variable '' not found in class closure

I am using latest version of intellij

I can see any local variable that I defined in the confirmationUser , what should I do to see registerUser in confirmationUser

when I run the page there is no problem and it is working but I need to debug because sometims I am getting null pointer exception and I want to directly know what is the problem.

Parent Page

```
  RegisterUser registerUser = null;
```

Child Page

```
    <% 
String x = "blabla";

  Boolean developer = registerUser.getPackage()!=null && registerUser.getPackage().getName().equals("Developer");%>
```

here I cannot see the registerUser variable However I can see x variable in the debugger

[image]

Comment: Have you declared the scope of the variable to be `request` scope?

Comment: <%   
        RegisterUser registerUser = null;

Comment: I declared it as this , the page is running but intellij cannot see  the variable

Comment: Add some more of your code to the question, please.

Comment: RegisterUser probably isn't in scope. Assuming you're using jstl, which you should be, you can try: `<c:set var="registeredUser" value="" scope="request"/>`, before your include fragment.

Comment: but the code is working I just cannot see it in the debug mode

Comment: I added <c:set var="registeredUser" value="" scope="request"/> and I am getting the same thing ... you can see figure above

Answer (score 3):

Most likely you need to:

1. Configure web facet for your project if you haven't done it;
2. Configure the directory containing your JSP pages as 'Web Resource Directory'.

I suspect (2) is not done and thus IntelliJ has trouble to resolve relative path of the included page.